# Adding Folium Popup Information to table beside map

Tags: python, django, pandas, folium

I am building a map website using Pandas, Django and Folium, with popups displaying information about servers in locations.

I am looking to include all the information that would display on a popup beside the map in a table.
[Here is an example popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqu3E.png)

I want it in a table like this [table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W30la.png)

Currently the table is a for loop iterating over a pandas dataframe. But that displays each row in the dataframe, not information about the specific marker, like the popup does.

The code look like:

```
locations = Location.objects.values()
loc_data = pd.DataFrame(locations)
for index, location_info in loc_data.iterrows():

        # Popup design through Iframe - html variable contains basic html to redesign the popup
    html=f"""
        <h1>{location_info['hostname']}</h1>
        <p>Node Attributes:
        <ul>
        <li>Structure Name: {location_info["structurename"]}</li>
        <li>Domain: {location_info["domain"]}</li>
        <li>IP Address: {location_info["ip"]}</li>
        <li>Persona: {location_info["personas"]}</li>
        </ul>
        {location_info["cube"]}
        </p>
        <a href={location_info["cubeurl"]} target = "_blank">Login to cube</a>
        """

    # Initialise the iframe as a variable and set the popup to be the iframe
    iframe = folium.IFrame(html=html, width=350, height=270)
    popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=2650)

    # Add Markers to the map based on criteria
    if location_info["cube"] == "Industrial Cube North":
        folium.Marker([location_info["latitude"], location_info["longitude"]], popup=popup, icon=folium.Icon(color='darkred'), tooltip=f'''{location_info["hostname"]}''').add_to(m)
    elif location_info["cube"] == "Industrial Cube South":
        folium.Marker([location_info["latitude"], location_info["longitude"]], popup=popup, icon=folium.Icon(color='green'), tooltip=f'''{location_info["hostname"]}''').add_to(m)

m=m._repr_html_() #updated
context = {'map': m, 'loc_data': loc_data}

return render(request, 'maps/map.html', context)
```

This is my html Django template: [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw0TD.png)

I think it needs some sort of on click event listener to display? Is this possible? Does anyone have any pointers?

EDIT - I have tried passing popup to context but its not iterable.. I also tried iframe but it displays a connection error screen

Comment: Maybe this link https://towardsdatascience.com/folium-map-how-to-create-a-table-style-pop-up-with-html-code-76903706b88a will help you with table.